# How to search paragraph(s) for objects

Tags: python, mysql, django, search

I'm looking for a way to parse objects out of naturally written text. I have a database of thousands of locations (City, State). As my users write posts, I would like to intelligently find and enrich locations being written about. For example, given the post:

> I had a really nice trip to **Portland** this weekend. It was beautiful and the climbing gyms are second to none.

I'd like to suggest Portland, OR and Portland, ME and ask the user to choose one.

Is there a name for this kind of search? I'm not even sure where to start.

EDIT: I'm currently using Python/Django and MySQL, but suggestions on any technology/platform would be useful.

Comment: Very much like how Stack Overflow suggests tags based on keywords while you're writing a question.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use NLP to extract the city (location) from your sentence.
See:
http://www.nltk.org/howto/relextract.html

then run a query against your database:

maybe like: 
select city, state from locations_table where city="Portland"

which will give you city, state pairs.